# How can i get the all digit of a number from 1st to last?

Tags: arithmetic

For example:
Given number=1234;
Failing,how can i separate all the digits from 1st to last?like 1,2,3,4

Comment: You can write it in base 10 :)

Comment: @yanbo To me it seems like, given $N$ the OP asks for a way to get the sequence $a_i$ of the decimal digits of $N$ in order of magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
$\lfloor \log_{10} x \rfloor$ is the number of digits (starting with $0$) and
$\left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^i} \right\rfloor {\rm mod}\ 10$ is the $i$-th digit (the digit with magnitude $10^i$).
Digits of naturals are counted from $0$ to $n-1$ where $n$ is the length of the string representation.

Comment: That should be $1+\lfloor\log_{10}x\rfloor$ digits, or $i$ counts down from $\lfloor\log_{10}x\rfloor$ to 0.

Comment: @Michael my notation is consistent with the $i$-th digit ;-). The $0$-th digit is the one with magnitude one. I elaborated on that a little bit.

Comment: @Michael Yes...1+⌊log10x⌋ is the number of digits..